# Why does this assembly code display a different number to what I specified?

Tags: assembly, numbers

I am learning how to use constants and have been able to load strings and integers into different registers. The only problem is, instead of `42` being displayed, `16777258` is being displayed instead. This is the same number all the time. If I change `_number` to a different value, I also get a different number displayed.

Why is this and what do I need to do?

This is my assembly code:

```
  .section  __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  .globl  _main
_main:
  #Backup base and stack pointer
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp

  #Move arguments
  leaq  L_.str(%rip), %rdi
  movl  _number(%rip), %esi
  #Should calll printf("%d", 42)
  callq _printf

  #return 0
  xorl  %eax, %eax

  popq  %rbp
  retq
  .section  __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
  .asciz  "%d"
  _number:
  .long 42
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I had to do was move the below code

```
_number:
.long 42
```

from the `.section  __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals` into `.data`. My code then looked like this:

```
  .section  __TEXT,__text,regular,pure_instructions
  .globl  _main
_main:
  #Backup base and stack pointer
  pushq %rbp
  movq  %rsp, %rbp

  #Move arguments
  leaq  L_.str(%rip), %rdi
  movl  _number(%rip), %esi
  #Should calll printf("%d", 42)
  callq _printf

  #return 0
  xorl  %eax, %eax

  popq  %rbp
  retq

  .data
  _number:
  .long 42

  .section  __TEXT,__cstring,cstring_literals
L_.str:
  .asciz  "%d"
```